# "If he was doing" vs. "If he were doing"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Could you tell me if both following sentences are perfectly natural and correct?

> If he **was** doing his homework, he would have more time to hang out with his friends.
>
> If he **were** doing his homework, he would have more time to hang out with his friends.

I'm aware that when the main verb in the if-clause is *be* then both *was* and *were* grammatically correct. *Were* is even more so, though. But, what about if it's part of the past pregressive in a condional sentence as in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware that when the main verb in the if-clause is be then both was and were grammatically correct. Were is even more so, though.

The thing to keep an eye on here is if the if-clause is based on a completely hypothetical or improbable event (an unreal conditional). In such a case, we would use *were*. Your example is one of these. It's hypothetical because he's NOT doing his homework. Thus, *were* is the only correct conjugation.

An example of when we would use *if he was*, is if we're talking about an event that did in fact take place. For instance,

> He was at home, doing his homework, officer.
>
> If he was doing his homework, then he has an alibi.

Comment: Re ***were** [doing something] is the only correct conjugation*, I don't think the *continuous* verb form is a good choice for OP's context in the first place. I'd much prefer to use Simple Past for "hypothetical / unreal *current* action" - *If he **did** his homework [he could do blah blah]*. That seems much more natural than *If he **were [to be] doing** it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Yeah, that's a good point. But somehow, the way OP wrote it sounds quite natural to me as a present progressive. When you say "if he did his homework" it sounds ambiguous, as you could be referring to a past opportunity as well as a present one. But "if he were doing his homework" sounds like he should be doing it right now, but isn't.

Comment: If the reference was *(were to have been? :)* to a hypothetical/unreal *past* action, I suggest we'd say *If he had done / were to have done / had have done [his homework]*. For things that aren't happening *now*, "past" tense seems right to me: *If he **loved** me he would marry me.*